# Splitting dataframe into multiple based on x and y values in data set and getting value counts Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with x and y coordinates, and I need to split it into a 10x10 grid (so 100 sections) based on the x and y values and retrieve the value counts for the class category. [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDzm1.png) I am very new to coding, so I really have no idea the best way to go about this. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: each box within the grid needs to be the same size, but the 'class' value count will vary

Comment: Welcome @TerynKoch. Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: @Teryn Koch is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408638/16343464) what you wanted to do or did I misinterpret the question? If not, can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the question.

Let's start from this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(100, size=100),
                   'y': np.random.randint(100, size=100),
                   'class': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEF'), size=100),
                  })
```

```
    x   y class
0  16  14     F
1  31  45     F
2  78  40     C
3  12   0     B
4  67  92     C
...
```

The goal is to group the data by (x,y) coordinates in a 10×10 grid.

Graphically, this would look like this:

[image: groups on a scatterplot]

First, create groups of x and y coordinates using [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with 10 bins:

```
df['group_x'] = pd.cut(df.x, bins=10)
df['group_y'] = pd.cut(df.y, bins=10)
```

This generates in my example the following intervals for x: `[(-0.099, 9.9] < (9.9, 19.8] < (19.8, 29.7] < (29.7, 39.6] ... (59.4, 69.3] < (69.3, 79.2] < (79.2, 89.1] < (89.1, 99.0]]`

Then [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the combination of groups, [count the values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of class and [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) on "class":

```
(df.groupby(['group_x', 'group_y'])
   ['class'].value_counts()
   .unstack(level='class')
   .fillna(0)
)
```

output:

```
class                        A  B  C  D  E  F
group_x       group_y                        
(-0.099, 9.9] (-0.099, 9.9]  0  0  1  0  0  0
              (19.8, 29.7]   0  1  2  0  0  1
              (29.7, 39.6]   1  0  1  0  0  0
              (49.5, 59.4]   0  0  0  2  0  0
              (59.4, 69.3]   0  0  0  0  0  1
              (89.1, 99.0]   0  0  1  0  0  0
(9.9, 19.8]   (-0.099, 9.9]  0  1  0  0  0  0
              (9.9, 19.8]    0  1  0  0  0  1
              (19.8, 29.7]   1  1  0  1  0  0
              (39.6, 49.5]   1  0  0  0  0  1
              (59.4, 69.3]   0  0  1  0  0  0
              (79.2, 89.1]   1  1  0  0  1  0
              (89.1, 99.0]   0  1  0  1  0  0
(19.8, 29.7]  (-0.099, 9.9]  0  0  0  1  0  0
              (9.9, 19.8]    0  0  0  0  0  1
              (29.7, 39.6]   0  0  0  1  0  0
              (59.4, 69.3]   0  0  0  2  0  0
              (69.3, 79.2]   0  1  0  1  0  1
              (79.2, 89.1]   1  0  0  0  1  0
              (89.1, 99.0]   0  0  0  0  1  0
...
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway!! This worked great. I super appreciate it.